# How to call recursively a function stored in a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I achieve that in Javascript?

```
exports.functions = {
    my_func: function (a) {
        my_func(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Name it!](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html)

Comment: @bergi what about this.my_func() ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yeah, that'll work as well when the function is guaranteed to be always called as a method on `functions`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function expression can have an optional name after the `function` keyword. The scope of this name is just the function body, and allows it to be called recursively:

```
exports.function = {
    my_func: function this_func(a) {
        this_func(a);
    }
}
```

You can also use its full name:

```
exports.function = {
    my_func: function(a) {
        exports.function.my_func(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: in the article Bergi pointed to in the comments on the question.. that 'optional' name isn't implemented properly in some interpeters.. not sure if JScript compatibility is worth consideration though.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Only IE had the problem AFAIK - *but* a function expression name still works in IE. In some IE versions the scope would just bleed to a binding in the current context as well which is a side-effect that can be largely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite ok as a standard, but you can easily achieve this like:

```
var foo = function(a) {
    foo(a);
}
exports.functions = {my_func: foo};
```

Your code does not work because in this case the hoisting is not done ok(well it's done ok) but not for what you need.